# Accidently Deleted a file of Huawei b310s-927 How to recover I did Telnet by using putty

Tags: terminal, router, huawei-mobile-services, firmware

I wanted to unlock a router (huawei b310s-927 21.333). when I login to the router by using putty software I use the rm -r command a delete a folder under the system folder (bin).

I that Folder there were some file files like commands (`rm , touch, vim ..etc`)
after deleting that folder, I was unable to use any command.

So I restarted by router but unfortunately my router stuck on one light. no firmware software is working to recover that file.

"Please note that the folder I deleted was a command files folder in that folder I see command name, we used in Linux terminal. "

Can anyone please help, how can I recover them or how can I do firmware on my router.